# Create Django user after retrieving token from Instagram

Tags: python, django, instagram

I don't want to use all the overhead from open packages and challenging myself to write my own Instagram django login. I already used python-instagram and get secret token from instagram api, like this:

```
# django view 
access_token = api.exchange_code_for_access_token(request.GET.get('code'))
```

Now I need to create django user and save this token?

I found https://github.com/evonove/django-oauth-toolkit witch gives me an idea how to working with oAuth2 tokens. But i just need to create django user and keep him logged-in bases on token. What should I do next?

Comment: I don't know if interpreted your question correctly, just checking: You don't want to use any existing package that does it but you want us to tell you how to do all the OAuth stuff manually?

Comment: something like that :) it sounds hard? i just don't want to use this huge overhead

Comment: I don't see what sounds hard here. You have already got the Instagram token, so you have already done the OAuth login dance. The only thing you need to do now is login a user, which is well covered in the Django docs. Where exactly are you having problems?

Comment: login bases on password, and i have only token? Sounds like i need some auth.backedn.OAuth, right? maybe you have some examples?